# Force CMake to execute code generator before anything else

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I can't seem to figure this out. I'm using catkin/CMake. Basically I want to generate an rqt_configure GUI.

However I want to auto-generate the config and message files for this. So I wrote a generator. Using `add_custom_target` I managed to get the script called:

```
add_custom_target(
    generate ALL
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    BYPRODUCTS cfg/${PROJECT_NAME}.cfg msg/${PROJECT_NAME}.msg launch/${PROJECT_NAME}.launch scripts/callback.py
    COMMAND rosrun my_generator my_generator.pc
)
```

As soon as I try to use the generated code catkin build fails:

```
    generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
        cfg/${PROJECT_NAME}.cfg
    )

    add_message_files(
        FILES ${PROJECT_NAME}.msg
    )

    generate_messages(
        DEPENDENCIES
    )
```

It says `add_message_files` can't find the generated file, and doesn't generate the file, even though `add_custom_target` comes before.

I just want to ensure `add_custom_target` is run first.

Everything I read about ensuring order says I should use add_depencies( generate), however I don't know which target to attach to to pre-empt these macros.

Comment: In any form, `add_custom_target`/`add_custom_command` are executed at build *stage*, which comes after *configuration* stage when `CMakeLists.txt` is parsed. But it looks like `add_message_files` wants to see the file **immediately**, at *configuration* stage. So you need to create the file with `execute_process`, which is also executed immediately.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you! It seems to work now. For some reason I had tried execute_process before, but it didn't generate at all.

Comment: If you got a working solution, please consider writing up a quick answer post, and marking as accepted.

Comment: @squareskittles do you mean me or Tsyvarev? I didn't want to steal his points.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Feel free to post one yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `add_message_files` wants to see the file **immediately**, at *configuration* stage, when CMake processes `CMakeLists.txt`. But `add_custom_target` executes its COMMAND only at the *build* stage.

You need to run your generator immediately, using [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/execute_process.html) instead:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND rosrun my_generator my_generator.pc
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

(It could be useful to pass additional `RESULT_VARIABLE` option, so it would be possible to check success of the command call).